# hadoop cluster: map task run only on one machine and not all

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have a `hadoop cluster of three machines` where one machine acts as both master and slave.

When I run [wordcount-example](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/), it run map tasks on two machines - `worker1` and `worker2`.  **But** when I run my own code, it runs only on one machine - `worker1`, how can I make map tasks run on all machines?

```
Input Split Locations

/default-rack/master
/default-rack/worker1
/default-rack/worker2
```

**FIXED!!!**

I added the following in my configuration of `mapred-site.xml` and it fixed it

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.map.tasks</name>
  <value>100</value>
</property>
```

Comment: The scheduling algorithm is the same for streaming and regular Java MR jobs. There shouldn't be any difference where the tasks are scheduled, unless the MR slots are not marked as free in the JobTracker.

Comment: Please describe in both cases what your input looks like. Things like: number of input files, files sizez and the compression that was used.

Comment: @Niels - The Input Split locations has been specified in the original query. Looks like the split locations is the same with/without streaming. The FIFO scheduling logic (default) is the same with/without streaming.

Comment: @Praveen - I do not understand what you just said. I indicated that daydreamer should indicate what his input looks like. I suspect he is running the two different jobs against different input files, and that his own job runs against either "small" files and/or "non-splittable" files.

Comment: @daydreamer - why did adding `mapred.map.tasks` solve the problem?

Comment: @Praveen, because by default there run only two map tasks per machine (I guess) and we can increase this number by adding mapred.map.tasks

Comment: @daydreamer - still not clear - how will increasing mapred.map.tasks from the default 2 to 100 make you job run on two nodes instead of one - I smell something :)

Comment: @PraveenSripati, I just did this and it worked, no other changes that I made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big is your input? Hadoop splits up the jobs into input splits, and if your file is too small, it will only have one split.

Try a larger file-- say around 1GB in size and see how mappers you get then.

---

You can also check to make sure that every TaskTracker is reporting properly to the JobTracker. If there is a TaskTracker that is not properly connected, it will not get tasks:

```
   $ hadoop job -list-active-trackers
```

This command should output all 3 of your hosts.